# iOS Time change notification and previous time

Tags: ios, date, synchronization, timeout

I have an application that works with **timeout** (let's say -> ring **in 3 days**). My problem occurs if a user **change the device local time** while being **offline** because I am **comparing two NSDate** (the final date and today) to check that timeout.

So I am trying to get notified **when** a user made a **significant time change** (several hours or days) in order to **update my timers depending on the difference between *before* and *after* the update**.

I found the *UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification*, which does :

> Posted when there is a significant change in time, for example, change to a new day (midnight), carrier time update, and change to or from daylight savings time.

That nearly fits but I can't figure out how to get the "old" time in order to get the difference. I can't rely on a webserver neither because the app should be running in offline mode.

Any idea or suggest is welcome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find a way to solve my problem by using the **CPU time** (which is always constantly increasing except on reboot).

First time the app is launched, I get the Real time and the CPU time.

Then, when I need to check if time has been changed, I just take

> the **Real time** at first, I add to it ( the **current CPU time** - the CPU time at first).

This give me the correct time.

> Note: take care to use the real CPU time, not the one used by timer because it's stop when device go to sleep.

Comment: if possible, please provide the code. So that it will be helpful to everyone.

Comment: 5 years later... sorry mate, I don't have the code anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

You should store the current time of your device, when your application goes into background. When the application comes into foreground, you should take the current time of your device. Now measure the difference between these 2 dates. If it is less than zero, it means, the user has set the device with previous date and you should throw the error of time out. If the difference is greater than 0, then you should compare current time with actual finish date.

One more indirect way is to start the location tracking of your device. Keep it on even when the app goes into background. When your didUpdateLocation delegate will hit by system, you will receive CLLocation object in argument. This location object is having currentTime details. Compare the time of last location and current location. If it is negative, user has bluffed with time. Its time to take the action.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea! But the problem remain, it isn't really accurate. let's say at 10am I leave the app with a timer that end in 5 hours, thus the prev_time would be 10:00. 4 hours later I set the app time to 11am (instead of 2pm) and I come back. So it is greater than 0 (11-10) and the timer is going to run for 4 hours more than what was plan.

Comment: wow, that's smart! The only problem is that GPS is not available in offline mode, but I can deal with that. Thanks again for the very quick help !

Comment: After some tries, even if it's really smart, it is still not accurate enought to me. It would be perfect when the device is not offline, because GPS would be available immediatly and that should work (but while online, I prefer to use a NTP). But has GPS is not available offline, the user can set the time 3 hours back, and come back online 10 hours later, and the same problem as the previous comment apply.

Comment: There is no relation of GPS component with data connection. You can receive location updates even when the device is offline. You can not receive the location update in airplane mode or you have not provided the rights on beginning of the application.

Comment: okay, what I called offline was, indeed, airplane mode. But I finally found a better way using the Kernel clock. I'll post an answer to explain it.